# Time out period in Java Web Service call

Tags: java, timeout

I have a web service with one exposed operation which does some specific job. What I want is, if the exposed operation is successfully called from Client (SOAP UI or Axis 2 or .Net or any other client) and if the exposed operation does not execute completely with a specified time (say 2 seconds), then the client must receive the time out error message. How do i handle the time out?

For example- Lets say the exposed operation is foo().
In foo(), there are three sub routines - routine1(), routine2(), routine3(), each taking 5 seconds to execute (in worst case) and the time out period specified is 10 seconds. In this case since it will take 15 seconds for foo() to execute completely, but the time out specified is 10 seconds, then calling foo() from any client should get timeout exception.

foo(){
   routine1 (),
 routine2(), 
 routine3() 
}

Comment: Set a read timeout at the client.

Comment: No the requirement is the exposed operation of the web-service should handle the time out period. Please let me know for any concrete solution.